# check soft keyboard state when pressed by back button

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, back-button

I have an Eidt Text area. After finished my input from soft keyboard, I hide the soft keyboard
by pressing Back Button. The question is that how can check its current state by programmatically(hidden or visible)

thanks.

Comment: Hope this work helps to check the visibility of keyboard.

[Check visibility of soft keyboard][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android

Comment: In this case if I edit the text it changes instantly, but what I need is It give one boolean when I press back button.

Comment: When I press the back button the method: onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent keyEvent) not called at the present of soft keyboard, after it vanishing it is called. the Developer website it has been said: Called when a key was pressed down and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity. So, for example, key presses while the cursor is inside a TextView will not trigger the event (unless it is a navigation to another object) because TextView handles its own key presses.

Comment: what is the mean (nless it is a navigation to another object) in there.